# Get a select value from a form and try query in mongodb

Tags: jquery, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I try to do a query in mongodb with my select value. I have a error `#<Object> is not a function`. I try the bracket notation but it's the same error.

```
for(var i = 0; i < axey.options.length; i++)
{       
  if(axey.options[i].selected == true)
  {
    axeyValues.push(axey.options[i].value);
    if ((Session.get("radioval") == "base100") &&  (Session.get("aggregation") != "Indicateurs"))
    {
      if (Session.get("categories") ==  "Deplacement")
      {
        value = Object.prototype.toString.apply(axey.options[i].value) ;
        /*var projection = {"fields" : {"_id" : 0}}; //bracket notation same error
        projection["fields"][value] = 1;*/
        console.log(Object.prototype.toString.apply(value)); // return [object string]
        data = Deplacement.find({value : 1}).value;
        console.log(data);
      }
      _tab[i] = data;
    }
  }        
}
```

my data :

```
 { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5878f6d36aacf11c9417be32"), 
    "Date" : ISODate("2000-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "Abonne au tarif " : 3, 
    "Abonnements" : 8, 
    "tout public" : 9, 
    "Tickets l'unit‚" : 9, 
    "Tickets" : 2, 
    "carnet" : 7
}
```

how I can do my query ?

Comment: Where in the code is the error being returned?

Comment: Are you trying to search for a document that has a `key` whose name you've figured out from your code? or are you looking for a key whose literal name is `value`? If the former, then the value of `value` needs to be a string, not an object.